# Direct specific vlans to specific WAN connections (2 ISP ,using USG Pro 4)

Tags: vlan, wide-area-network, ubiquiti

**ISP-A** : 1Gbps fiber line **static IP address** and **ISP-B** : 1Gbps fiber connection with **dynamic IP address**.

We wanted to know if it was possible using static routing to create a method to direct specific vlans to specific WAN connections

We currently use a **Unifi pro 4 gateway router** and recently purchased a second line as a backup but we can see there are only 2 methods of function. Fail-over and distributed. The failover we understand will only kick in when the primary line has been detected as offline and the distributed means that it will only use the internet bandwidth of the first line up to a certain percentage before it will utilize the second internet bandwidth from the second line. This will still equal more or less the same thing as the single line which we already had of 1gb.

Our idea was to try lighten the load of specific vlans by directing them to the second wan instead of the primary wan.

**Current setup:**

We have have different Vlans, one for admin staff , one for teachers and a couple more for certain purposes.

The modem from ISP-A connects to the USG Pro 4 through an ethernet cable on port WAN1 and then an ethernet cable connects the USG Pro 4 ,from the LAN1 port, with the our main Ubiquity switch.

When we try to do the same with the modem from ISB-B , connect it to WAN2 port and then use the LAN2 port on the USG pro 4 to connect it to another switch, the light never comes on for WAN2.

We wanted to know if it was possible with our current vlan setup (which works perfectly) to utilize the second internet connection by telling certain vlans to piggy-back off the second internet connection to lighten the load of the first internet connection.to split the

Can we in practice do this or do we need 2 seperate gateways...to split the distribution of networks to their internet connections?